# iOS DOxygen adding docSet to Xcode Documents

Tags: iphone, xcode, terminal, doxygen, docset

Hey Everyone just having a problem with DOxygen, Ive generated my documentation and its allthere, but i find i am unable to add it to Xcode.

I currently have a script which takes the HTML directory containing all the files, and generates the .docset file.

```
# Run the makefile. The --silent parameter stops it from spamming us with too much output.
#/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil
make --silent -C "$DOCSET_OUTPUT/html" install

# Load docset
osascript "$[location of personal library]/Scripts/XcodeLoadDocSet.scpt"          

"~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/$DOXYGEN_ID.docset"
```

This should also add the item to xcode, but running it manually reveals a problem..

```
 /Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil index com.[my app].docset
 make: /Developer/usr/bin/docsetutil: No such file or directory
 make: *** [docset] Error 1
```

This is what i have atm for the makefile,

```
DOCSET_NAME=com.[my app].docset
DOCSET_CONTENTS=$(DOCSET_NAME)/Contents
DOCSET_RESOURCES=$(DOCSET_CONTENTS)/Resources
DOCSET_DOCUMENTS=$(DOCSET_RESOURCES)/Documents
DESTDIR=~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
XCODE_INSTALL=$(shell xcode-select -print-path)

all: docset

docset:
mkdir -p $(DOCSET_DOCUMENTS)
cp Nodes.xml $(DOCSET_RESOURCES)
cp Tokens.xml $(DOCSET_RESOURCES)
cp Info.plist $(DOCSET_CONTENTS)
tar --exclude $(DOCSET_NAME) \
    --exclude Nodes.xml \
    --exclude Tokens.xml \
    --exclude Info.plist \
    --exclude Makefile -c -f - . \
    | (cd $(DOCSET_DOCUMENTS); tar xvf -)
$(XCODE_INSTALL)/usr/bin/docsetutil index $(DOCSET_NAME)
rm -f $(DOCSET_DOCUMENTS)/Nodes.xml
rm -f $(DOCSET_DOCUMENTS)/Info.plist
rm -f $(DOCSET_DOCUMENTS)/Makefile
rm -f $(DOCSET_RESOURCES)/Nodes.xml
rm -f $(DOCSET_RESOURCES)/Tokens.xml

install: docset
mkdir -p $(DESTDIR)
cp -R $(DOCSET_NAME) $(DESTDIR)

uninstall:
rm -rf $(DESTDIR)/$(DOCSET_NAME)

always:
```

If anyone has had a similer problem please let me know.

Cheers
Michael.

Comment: No bash here. Tagging for make.

Comment: Also have now fixed it so it is generating the docset, but now i cannot move the file from the local directory to the xcode documentation directory, If i run the script i have manually outside of xcode, i get a bad xml error, which i can view the HTML site locally and it works fine. So i think the error is permissions to write to the xcode dir. Ive unhidden the library so it should be working...but it isnt.

Answer (score 3):

With Xcode 4, docsetutil is located under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/`